# Combine the result of a list of parallel tasks to a single HashMap using RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I have a `List<Task>`, where `Task` is an interface with a single method that returns a `Map<String, JsonElement>`. How can I execute the `List<Task>` in parallel and return a new `HashMap` with the combined result of each `Task`?

I currently have this:

```
List<Task> tasks = getTasks();

Observable.from(tasks)
    .flatMap(new Func1<Task, Observable<Map<String, JsonElement>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Map<String, JsonElement>> call(Task task) {
            return Observable.just(task.get());
        }
    });

// group into single Map<String,JsonElement>
// create Observable<Map<String,JsonElement>> with all results
```

Comment: By what value you want combine/group your `Task` in new `HashMap`?

Comment: The result of each Task.get() should be combined in the new ```HashMap``` using ```map.putAll()```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `defer` to encapsulate the `Map` per subscription and a `Scheduler` based on the size thread pool you'd like:

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5));
Observable.defer(() -> {
  final Map<String, JsonElement> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
  return Observable
    .from(tasks)
    .flatMap(task -> 
      Observable
        .fromCallable(task -> task.get())
        .doOnNext(mp -> map.putAll(mp)) 
        .subscribeOn(scheduler))
    .ignoreElements()
    .concatWith(Observable.just(map));
});
```

Note that the choice of `Scheduler` will depend on the nature of the task being performed. You might be happy with `Schedulers.computation()` if it's CPU dominated.